# how to extract asin from an amazon product page

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

I have the following webpage [Product page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B014MHZ90M) and I'm trying to get the ASIN from it (in this case ASIN=B014MHZ90M) and I don't have a clue on how to get it from the page.

I'm using Python 3.4, Scrapy and the following code:

```
hxs = Selector(response)
product_name = "".join(hxs.xpath('//span[contains(@class,"a-text-ellipsis")]/a/text()').extract())
product_model = hxs.xpath('//body//div[@id="buybox_feature_div"]//form[@method="post"]/input[@id="ASIN"/text()').extract()
```

In this way I don't get the required field (the ASIN number).

1. What should I do in order to get the product model (ASIN)?

2.Is there a way to debug such code (I'm using PyCharm). I could not use debugger but only run it without seeing what's going on there in 'slow motion'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the Amazon page you linked, the ASIN number appears in the "Product Details" section. Using the scrapy shell the following xpath

```
response.xpath('//li[contains(.,"ASIN: ")]//text()').extract()
```

returns

```
[u'ASIN: ', u'B014MHZ90M']
```

For debugging XPATHs I always use `scrapy shell` and Firebug for Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it still doesn't return the ASIN. Iv'e printed (resoponse.url) and got the following link:
[response.url](http://www.amazon.com/PLAY-STORE-Lightweight-Heaproduct-reviewshone-Bluetooth/product-reviews/B014MHZ90M/ref=sr_1_1/176-6294413-3388143?s=aht&ie=UTF8&qid=1447148770&sr=1-1&keywords=bluetooth&pageSize=50&sortBy=recent). How can I extract ASIN from this page?

Comment: @LiorMagen what did you do to get the link you've supplied in response.url in your comment? My xpath produces a list whose second element is the value you said you where looking for. Have you tried this in `scrapy shell`?

Comment: Iv'e created a parser for the product page and in the product page I used your code and it works like a charm now. Thank you Steve.

Comment: @LiorMagen care to share?

Comment: @AviParshan Hi, sorry but it was toooo long time ago, I don't really remeber.

Answer (score 4):

you can extract B014MHZ90M from the response.url

```
response.url.split("/dp/")[1]
```

response.url.split("/dp/")[1] = B014MHZ90M

response.url.split("/dp/")[0] = http://www.amazon.com

Comment: I think product_id present in the URL can be different from ASIN. For Eg:-  in the link 
 - https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00GSSVVV0?th=1, the one present after dp/ is product id and you can find ASIN by going to the page and looking at product description. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

I use this:

```
re.match("http[s]?://www.amazon.(\w+)(.*)/(dp|gp/product)/(?P<asin>\w+).*", url, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get that from the url.

```
r = re.search('www.amazon.com/dp/(.+)/', response.url)
print r.group(1)
```

Comment: The products url sometimes begins with "/gp/product/" instead of "/dp/".
And it's possible too that add the product url after the amazon domain.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.amazon.com/gp/seller/asin-upc-isbn-info.html

> Amazon Standard Identification Numbers (ASINs) are unique blocks of 10
>   letters and/or numbers that identify items.

Your best option and probably the easiest one is to run a regex on the URL looking for a 10 char string between two "/".

```
'/\w{10}/'
```

You can then simply omit the "/"s from the result.