# Splitting strings in a list by the first 10 characters, Python

Tags: python, list, split

I am trying to get the ASIN number for each product on Amazon which is the first ten digits after dp/. I have gotten to the point where I have the digits but still have the junk after it. Any help?

```
   product_lst = [
            "https://www.amazon.com/Bentgo-Kids-Prints-Camouflage-5-Compartment/dp/B07R2CNSTK/ref=zg_bs_toys-and-games_home_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=S3ESVW604M2GF8VYYVAZ",
            "https://www.amazon.com/Hamdol-Inflatable-Swimming-Sprinkler-Full-Sized/dp/B08SLYY1WD/?_encoding=UTF8&smid=AYKJMONAWDIKA&pf_rd_p=287d7433-71c6-4904-99b3-55833d0daaa0&pd_rd_wg=lMKJu&pf_rd_r=CR8F460JV643467SAG8Q&pd_rd_w=KgWnp&pd_rd_r=0e298b4a-6e52-4688-87bb-482fb6c1a56b&ref_=pd_gw_deals",
            "https://www.amazon.com/Fire-TV-Stick-4K-with-Alexa-Voice-Remote/dp/B079QHML21?ref=deals_primeday_deals-grid_slot-5_21f9_dt_dcell_img_0_ca4a9dae",
            "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B089RDSML3",
            "https://www.amazon.com/Lucky-Brand-Burnout-Notch-Shirt/dp/B081J8SGH7/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&pf_rd_i=7147441011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=e6aa97f3-9bc4-42c5-ac38-37844f71b469&pf_rd_r=S2F3A95JN2FDGBQ4V048&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-9&pf_rd_t=101&qid=1624427428&s=apparel&sr=1-2"
        ]
for url in product_lst:
    product_lst = url.split("dp/")
    for url in product_lst:
        del product_lst[::2]
    print(product_lst)
```

Output:

> ['B07R2CNSTK/ref=zg_bs_toys-and-games_home_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=S3ESVW604M2GF8VYYVAZ']
> ['B08SLYY1WD/?*encoding=UTF8&smid=AYKJMONAWDIKA&pf_rd_p=287d7433-71c6-4904-99b3-55833d0daaa0&pd_rd_wg=lMKJu&pf_rd_r=CR8F460JV643467SAG8Q&pd_rd_w=KgWnp&pd_rd_r=0e298b4a-6e52-4688-87bb-482fb6c1a56b&ref*=pd_gw_deals']
> ['B079QHML21?ref=deals_primeday_deals-grid_slot-5_21f9_dt_dcell_img_0_ca4a9dae']
> ['B089RDSML3']
> ['B081J8SGH7/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&pf_rd_i=7147441011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=e6aa97f3-9bc4-42c5-ac38-37844f71b469&pf_rd_r=S2F3A95JN2FDGBQ4V048&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-9&pf_rd_t=101&qid=1624427428&s=apparel&sr=1-2']

Comment: You're reusing variable names for the outer loops and inner variable

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. As Sayse said, don't reuse the same variable name for two different things. This invariably leads to bugs in your code.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59857225/extract-amzon-asin-from-url-re-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33625602/how-to-extract-asin-from-an-amazon-product-page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For searches in text the [module `re` (regex)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) is a good choice:

```
product_lst = [
"https://www.amazon.com/Bentgo-Kids-Prints-Camouflage-5-Compartment/dp/B07R2CNSTK/ref=zg_bs_toys-and-games_home_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=S3ESVW604M2GF8VYYVAZ",
"https://www.amazon.com/Hamdol-Inflatable-Swimming-Sprinkler-Full-Sized/dp/B08SLYY1WD/?_encoding=UTF8&smid=AYKJMONAWDIKA&pf_rd_p=287d7433-71c6-4904-99b3-55833d0daaa0&pd_rd_wg=lMKJu&pf_rd_r=CR8F460JV643467SAG8Q&pd_rd_w=KgWnp&pd_rd_r=0e298b4a-6e52-4688-87bb-482fb6c1a56b&ref_=pd_gw_deals",
"https://www.amazon.com/Fire-TV-Stick-4K-with-Alexa-Voice-Remote/dp/B079QHML21?ref=deals_primeday_deals-grid_slot-5_21f9_dt_dcell_img_0_ca4a9dae",
"https://www.amazon.com/dp/B089RDSML3",
"https://www.amazon.com/Lucky-Brand-Burnout-Notch-Shirt/dp/B081J8SGH7/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&pf_rd_i=7147441011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=e6aa97f3-9bc4-42c5-ac38-37844f71b469&pf_rd_r=S2F3A95JN2FDGBQ4V048&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-9&pf_rd_t=101&qid=1624427428&s=apparel&sr=1-2"
]

import re

results = []
for url in product_lst:
    m = re.search(r"/dp/([^/?]+)",url)
    if m:
        results.append(m.groups()[0])
print(results)
```

Output:

```
['B07R2CNSTK', 'B08SLYY1WD', 'B079QHML21', 'B089RDSML3', 'B081J8SGH7']
```

I use  `r"/dp/([^/?]+)"` as pattern wich boils down to a grouped match for anything after `/dp/` and then matches all things up to the next `/` or `?`.

You can test regexes online - I use http://regex101.com (for complex ones) - it can even provide python code based on what you insert in its fields (not using that though ;o) )

---

You can change your own code to

```
for url in product_lst:
    part = url.split("dp/")
    if len(part) > 1:            # blablubb dp/ more things => 2 or more parts
        print(part[1])           # print whats is left after dp/
```

to avoid overwriting your list `product_lst` - but you will still need to trim stuff after / and ? with it.

Answer (score 1):

After you `split()` on the `'dp/'`, there is absolutely no reason to loop. You know exactly where the data is that you want, so just get it directly:

```
   product_lst = [
            "https://www.amazon.com/Bentgo-Kids-Prints-Camouflage-5-Compartment/dp/B07R2CNSTK/ref=zg_bs_toys-and-games_home_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=S3ESVW604M2GF8VYYVAZ",
            "https://www.amazon.com/Hamdol-Inflatable-Swimming-Sprinkler-Full-Sized/dp/B08SLYY1WD/?_encoding=UTF8&smid=AYKJMONAWDIKA&pf_rd_p=287d7433-71c6-4904-99b3-55833d0daaa0&pd_rd_wg=lMKJu&pf_rd_r=CR8F460JV643467SAG8Q&pd_rd_w=KgWnp&pd_rd_r=0e298b4a-6e52-4688-87bb-482fb6c1a56b&ref_=pd_gw_deals",
            "https://www.amazon.com/Fire-TV-Stick-4K-with-Alexa-Voice-Remote/dp/B079QHML21?ref=deals_primeday_deals-grid_slot-5_21f9_dt_dcell_img_0_ca4a9dae",
            "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B089RDSML3",
            "https://www.amazon.com/Lucky-Brand-Burnout-Notch-Shirt/dp/B081J8SGH7/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&pf_rd_i=7147441011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=e6aa97f3-9bc4-42c5-ac38-37844f71b469&pf_rd_r=S2F3A95JN2FDGBQ4V048&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-9&pf_rd_t=101&qid=1624427428&s=apparel&sr=1-2"
        ]
for url in product_lst:
    split_lst = url.split("dp/")
    print(split_lst[1][:10]
```

I assume that the ASIN is always 10 characters. Adjust the splice if there are more characters and it is always fixed. Otherwise you will need to find a different appproach.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get the ASIN without splitting the data.

```py
product_lst = [
            "https://www.amazon.com/Bentgo-Kids-Prints-Camouflage-5-Compartment/dp/B07R2CNSTK/ref=zg_bs_toys-and-games_home_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=S3ESVW604M2GF8VYYVAZ",
            "https://www.amazon.com/Hamdol-Inflatable-Swimming-Sprinkler-Full-Sized/dp/B08SLYY1WD/?_encoding=UTF8&smid=AYKJMONAWDIKA&pf_rd_p=287d7433-71c6-4904-99b3-55833d0daaa0&pd_rd_wg=lMKJu&pf_rd_r=CR8F460JV643467SAG8Q&pd_rd_w=KgWnp&pd_rd_r=0e298b4a-6e52-4688-87bb-482fb6c1a56b&ref_=pd_gw_deals",
            "https://www.amazon.com/Fire-TV-Stick-4K-with-Alexa-Voice-Remote/dp/B079QHML21?ref=deals_primeday_deals-grid_slot-5_21f9_dt_dcell_img_0_ca4a9dae",
            "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B089RDSML3",
            "https://www.amazon.com/Lucky-Brand-Burnout-Notch-Shirt/dp/B081J8SGH7/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&pf_rd_i=7147441011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=e6aa97f3-9bc4-42c5-ac38-37844f71b469&pf_rd_r=S2F3A95JN2FDGBQ4V048&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-9&pf_rd_t=101&qid=1624427428&s=apparel&sr=1-2"
             ]

ASIN=[]
for url in product_lst:
    idx = url.find("/dp/")
    ASIN.append(url[idx+4:idx+14])

print(ASIN)
```

output

```py
['B07R2CNSTK', 'B08SLYY1WD', 'B079QHML21', 'B089RDSML3', 'B081J8SGH7']
```